# Remove metal sock from Honda Civic 2006 handbrake lever

Tags: honda, repair, handbrake

I've got a Honda Civic 2006 and the handbrake lever cracked near the top. I've got a new button assembly off ebay but it seems as though the old part has snapped off inside the metal lever. To access this, I'll need to remove the metal sock around it.

[image]

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I've never taken one apart, but I'd suspect you should take the center console completely out, then you can slide the outer part off from the handle.